# How can I compare these 2 dates and excludes instances that are the same?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables, orders and transactions. The orders table has 1 row per order, and the transactions table has multiple rows per order.

I want the check which orders have a different OrderDate compared to the FIRST instance of a transaction row with that same OrderNumber. I have tried the query below. But look at some of the records coming back - it's still returning some rows where the first ever transactions did actually take place on the same date as the OrderDate. It seems to still be querying on the second, third, fourth etc transactions that exist against that OrderNumber. I want it to only query on the first - hence I used ORDER BY Id LIMIT 0,1 - but it's not right.

```
SELECT
    o.ordernumber,
    Date(OrderDate),
    Date((
        SELECT
            TransDate
        FROM
            transactions
        WHERE
            OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
        ORDER BY
            Id
        LIMIT 0,
        1
    )) AS TransDate
FROM
    transactions AS t
JOIN orders AS o ON o.OrderNumber = t.OrderNumber
WHERE
    STATUS = 'booking'
AND date(OrderDate) != Date(TransDate)
ORDER BY
    o.OrderDate ASC
```

**123456789 2015-04-13  2015-04-13**

**123456788 2015-09-28  2015-10-05**

The first row shouldn't be included!

Comment: Can you show a sample data and what would be the result from that sample data?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the transactions table in the `from` clause.  You don't need it.  However, to get the value for comparison, you can't reference the date defined in the `select`.  You *can* use a MySQL extension:

```
SELECT o.ordernumber, Date(o.OrderDate),
       (SELECT date(TransDate)
        FROM transactions t
        WHERE t.OrderNumber = o.OrderNumber
        ORDER BY t.Id
        LIMIT 0, 1
       ) AS TransDate
FROM orders o
WHERE o.STATUS = 'booking'
HAVING date(OrderDate) <> TransDate
ORDER BY o.OrderDate ASC;
```

Comment: What is the extensions? As I still get [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'TransDate' in 'where clause'

Comment: @JamesWilson . . . This query has no `TransDate` reference in any `WHERE` clause, so that seems like a highly improbably error.

Comment: OK so at the moment I get: Unknown column 'o.OrderDate' in 'having clause'